# Error "QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication" when creating an application

Tags: c++, qt5

I'm trying to create a simple application that displays a picture from the Internet, but I can't resolve the "QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication" error

```
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QHBoxLayout>
    #include <QLabel>
    #include <QNetworkAccessManager>
    #include <QNetworkReply>

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        QApplication app(argc, argv); // Создаем экземпляр QApplication

        QWidget window;
        window.setWindowTitle("Пример вывода картинки из интернета");

        QLabel imageLabel(&window);

        QNetworkAccessManager manager;

        QUrl imageUrl("https://sun9-1.userapi.com/impf/c623123/v623123282/29de1/FO6lzwhA0Y8.jpg?      size=1280x800&quality=96&sign=1ef39f62b38765e2fc1217b3a2a156ba&c_uniq_tag=PX0ojl482fxtB_EqARnEWK5oF-4NsVeCCG7NeHv9lZA&type=album");

        QNetworkRequest request(imageUrl);
    
        QNetworkReply* reply = manager.get(request);
    
        QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [&]() {
            if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
       
                QPixmap pixmap;
                pixmap.loadFromData(reply->readAll());
                imageLabel.setPixmap(pixmap);

                imageLabel.setFixedSize(pixmap.size());

                QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(&window);
                layout->addWidget(&imageLabel);
                window.setLayout(layout);
                window.show();
            }
            else {
                qDebug() << "Error loading image:" << reply->errorString();
            }
            reply->deleteLater();
           });

        return app.exec();
    }
```

if the QEventLoop problem cannot be solved, are there alternatives?

All the solutions to this error on the Internet did not help me

Comment: Can't reproduce (MacOS 10.13.6 + Qt5.15.2).

Comment: In cases like this it's often useful to install your own [`Qt` message handler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler).  Then set a breakpoint on it under the debugger -- the backtrace should give you more information about the actual location of the problematic code.

Answer (score 0):

Move all of that code into the callback of a single-shot `QTimer`:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
// other stuff       
QTimer::singleShot(0, [=]() {

        QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;

        QUrl imageUrl("https://sun9-1.userapi.com/impf/c623123/v623123282/29de1/FO6lzwhA0Y8.jpg?      size=1280x800&quality=96&sign=1ef39f62b38765e2fc1217b3a2a156ba&c_uniq_tag=PX0ojl482fxtB_EqARnEWK5oF-4NsVeCCG7NeHv9lZA&type=album");

        QNetworkRequest request(imageUrl);
    
        QNetworkReply* reply = manager->get(request);
    
        QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, manager, &QObject::deleteLater);
        QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [&]() {
            if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
       
                QPixmap pixmap;
                pixmap.loadFromData(reply->readAll());
                imageLabel.setPixmap(pixmap);

                imageLabel.setFixedSize(pixmap.size());

                QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(&window);
                layout->addWidget(&imageLabel);
                window.setLayout(layout);
                window.show();
            }
            else {
                qDebug() << "Error loading image:" << reply->errorString();
            }
            reply->deleteLater();
           });
});

return app.exec();
```

This works because `QTimer::singleShot` adds a timer to the (not yet running) event loop. The call to `app.exec()` will kick off the event loop and it will immediately run the timer callback with a running event loop.

I also made a small change to your code because `manager` must be kept alive until the reply arrives.

Comment: The error remains
``